# Fastest way to print lowercase to uppercase alphabet bash

Tags: bash

I need to print the following using `bash`

```
.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

What I have so far:

```
echo -n "."; for l in {a..z}; do echo -n $l; done
```

This will print:

`.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` but I also need the uppercase letters.

I am trying to do this on one line, so preferably same for loop.

---

I do not want to type out the alphabet by hand.

Comment: If you are talking about performance, the fastest way is `echo ".abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"`

Comment: The alphabet is more or less constant: just hardcode it, don't generate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo . {a..z} {A..Z}| tr -d ' '
.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: Yet an easier way. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You could use two brace expansions:

```
$ printf -v str '%s' . {a..z} {A..Z}
$ echo "$str"
.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```